# Restore "loud volume, long periods" notification in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, audio, lg-g3

I am running Lollipop 5.0/CloudyG3 2.5 and G3 Tweaksbox. Is it possible to restore the "loud volume, long periods" notifications?
I would like to have the volume limiter that this notification provides.

I've tried rebooting my device and restoring the setting via Tweaksbox, but neither action helped.

Comment: Try to reboot your device, I think that I am getting that notification every time I reboot my phone.

Comment: No, that hasn't worked. First thing I tried.

Comment: @Chapz, since you also know something about this problem, could you provide a screenshot? I can't find anything on google by searching "loud volume, long periods".

Comment: @Firelord He/she is speaking of the volume warning that appeared with android k that displayed a warning before letting the volume exceed 10. It was removed with lollipop.

Comment: [Is this what you meant?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xevif.jpg) @EthanZ

Comment: @EthanZ But that is actually the same thing I posted, with the difference that mine is on Lollipop and yours is for Android 4.x.

Comment: @Firelord the dreaded scrolling down. I see it now. From my mobile perspective it looked like just the volume bar. Yes, that's what I was speaking of, it disappeared from my device on lollipop just as it did on MauF's device. Deleting now irrelevant comments.

Comment: @Firelord That's exactly what I meant. But it does exist in Lollipop, since I know that, by mistake, I pressed on the accept button. I was wondering if there is a way to edit some system file to restore the notification.

Comment: In my CyanogenMod 12, setting the value of key `unsafe_volume_music_active_ms` to 0 followed by a reboot restored it. If you're certain your ROM does have that safe sound setting, then there must be a key in a table of  `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`. In my ROM, the table is named `secure` and I did `adb shell su -c content update --uri content://settings/secure --bind value:s:0 --where "name='unsafe_volume_music_active_ms'"`. Change the table and key name  with the ones appropriate with the ones in your ROM.

Comment: Interesting! I will definitely look into it. I currently am on Cloudy, but will certainly search for that table in settings.db. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <s>The volume warning was removed with Android Lollipop.</s> It
>   appears that this is in lollipop, but it is either very buggy
>   or *extremely* passive.

Read the comments. Many users found it to be more of an annoyance than a useful feature. If you still want this feature, there are plenty of apps you can download that will limit the max volume of your device as KitKat did.

Comment: Is this absolutely true? It's been removed? I can almost swear that I pressed on the "accept" button while in Lollipop.

Comment: Found and downloaded an app from Play store. Thanks.

Comment: @MauF I never saw it and I use a Moto x. Motorola is usually VERY careful to deviate as little as possible from vanilla android. If anyone can prove this wrong, I'll happily admit I'm incorrect on that.

Comment: @MauF So I have a story. I rescind what I said. This menu is in android L. However, it appears to be _very_ buggy. My device's volume randomly lowered itself today in my car. It was this exact menu. Then the kicker- I can't get it to come back, even though I had selected cancel. This is the first and only time I have seen the warning in Lollipop and I don't think I will ever see it again. Bug or just more passive? I don't know.

Comment: The plot thickens and gets weird.